# Best practice for storing config data

Tags: java, spring, class, config

What is the best procedure for storing **configuration data**?
I have several classes that require some configuration data that is only needed in their class.
Should I load all this data from a configuration file or should I hardcode it into the classes?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: It depends: What is this "configuration data" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your question:

> Should I load all this data from a configuration file or should I hardcode it into the classes?

Basically if you hard code some value into the class, you don't intend to change that value **in different environments**. Each such a change would require re-compilation of the project.

For example if you have a constant for `PI=3.14` it doesn't make sense to use different values for different environments.

Alternatively if you go with configuration files, the update of such a file that can be supplied with a deployment script is much easier.

An example of this can be a host/port of the database. Development might use one host, production might use another.

**So you should decide what works for you best.**

This is common for all types of applications (not only spring boot driven).

Now its true that in spring boot you can create a configuration file (properties or yaml) and place it into the artifact (by putting it into `src/resources/` or `src/resources/config`).

For some situations its good enough, for others you might use another way of configuration.

I don't refer managing secrets here, this is a more advanced stuff, but in general you won't want to manage things like passwords neither in the source code (hard coded) nor in the configuration file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im storing different URLs my application is calling.